# Назначить имя для кнопок в массиве swift 3

Tags: массивы, ios, swift, button, swift3

У меня есть массив кнопок в количестве 12 и массив цифр в количестве 12. Мне надо на каждую кнопку назначить цифру. Как сделать? Спасибо.

```
let temp = [6, 25, 0, 90, 52, 55, 82, 75, 5, 79, 77, 64]
let keyboardArray = [keyboardView.btn1,
                             keyboardView.btn2,
                             keyboardView.btn3,
                             keyboardView.btn4,
                             keyboardView.btn5,
                             keyboardView.btn6,
                             keyboardView.btn7,
                             keyboardView.btn8,
                             keyboardView.btn9,
                             keyboardView.btn10,
                             keyboardView.btn11,
                             keyboardView.btn12]


        for button in keyboardArray {

            for i in 0 ..< temp.count {
                button?.setTitle(String(describing: temp[i]), for: .normal)
            }
        }
```

Вот так делаю не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in 0..temp.count {
    keyboardView[i].setTitle(String(describing: temp[i]), for: .normal)
}
```

Сам не проврял, возможно надо будет каситить в button либо где то разворачивать

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! Но исправьте ответ for _ in keyboardArray {
                for i in 0 ..< temp.count {
                    keyboardArray[i]?.setTitle(String(describing: temp[i]), for: .normal)
                }
            }

Comment: внешний for не нужен